# Configuring HikariCP with Mongo Reactive Repositories

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hikaricp

So I have a Spring Boot application which uses mongodb and reactive mongo repositories. I've run into this error on any endpoint I call, which has prompted me to get HikariCP or some other type of connection management system in place.

```
Too many operations are already waiting for a connection. Max number of operations (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many operations are already waiting for a connection. Max number of operations (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded."
```

I'm not 100% sure why my small service has used 500 connections, but I also noticed that it tries to open almost 100 connections the first time it gets called through the service.

Here is my main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;

@SpringBootApplications
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class HistorianApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and my Application.properties:

```
#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.type=reactive
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=Application
```

Most solutions have hikari configuration done through a bean, however I'm wondering if theres a way I can configure as much of the information possible in the .properties file.